# Javascript issue with math calculations

Tags: javascript, floating-accuracy

Why is it if I do this in javascript, I get the following result:

1234.56 * 10 = 12345.599999999999

It should be 123456.  How can I get around this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "doing it with jQuery". jQuery is a DOM manipulation extension, not a math library. Can you please post a code sample?

Comment: Also, it would be 12345.6 - you'd have to multiply by 100 to get 123456.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken

Answer (score 3):

Floating points are not exact, since there are ifinite numbers at their range [or in any range to be more exact], and only a finite number of bits to store this data.

Have a look at [what every programmer should know about floating point arithmetics](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 3):

Another easy solution:

```
parseFloat((1234.56 * 10).toPrecision(12))
```

and the result will be: 12345.6, and YES... it works with decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, floating points and so on.

Easy solution would be to do something like this:

```
var answer = parseInt(1234.56 * 10);
```

Or just use Math.round?

Answer (score 0):

All numbers in JS are internally defined by float and drop the less significant digits if needed.

```
(10000000000000000000000000000 + 1) == 10000000000000000000000000000
// this will return true
```

And javascript is well known for droping bits quite often in numbers. So handle with care